# Mpi install failure for anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, mpi, conda, mpi4py

System information: 
Windows 10 64-bit.
Anaconda 3.6.

When I try to install mpi4py through `conda install mpi4py` or `conda install -c intel mpi4py` [as this link states](https://anaconda.org/intel/mpi4py) I get a failed error:

`LinkError: pre-link script failed for package defaults::mpi4py-2.0.0-py36_1`

Then it does a roll back.  Is there a specific approach to installing it?